# How to Avoid ValueError: Columns must be Same as Key

Tags: python, group-by

I am trying to get the earliest date by person, I am using groupby against the adjusted_id. Below is an example what I mean.

```
Adjusted_id        ID       Name        Emp_type         Hire_date
     1             11     John Doe      Contractor       1/22/2002
     1             11     John Doe      Contractor       1/22/2002
     1            101     Doe, John     Employee         3/17/2006
     2             22     Sallie Mae    Contractor       8/12/2017
     2             22     Saliie Mae    Contractor       8/12/2017
     2            202     Mae, Sallie   Employee         5/20/2020
```

I want to get the minimum date for the Hire_date however when I try and groupby the adjusted id I get a Value Error. I am assuming that is because when I get the minimum date I am only getting one value by adjusted id when it wants 3. Thats what I assume but I am not sure.

Comment: The warning means that there is more than 2 rows that have the same `adjusted_id`

Comment: So what I should use is  .tail()?